# Understanding contradictions and how to deal with them when they arise in 1st order logic arguments

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Consider the statement: "Prove that $X \cup (Y \setminus X) \subseteq X \cup Y$" (I believe the two unions are actually equal, but for the sake of this question, that is not relevant).

Converting this into a first order statement that I want to prove (if this is incorrect, please let me know and I will change it for clarity):

$$\forall a,X,Y\big(a \in X \cup (Y\setminus X) \rightarrow a \in X \cup Y\big)$$

Note the following:

$$a\in X \cup (Y \setminus X) \iff a \in X \lor (a \in Y \land a \notin X)$$

$$\neg(a \in Y \setminus X) \iff a \notin Y \lor a \in X$$

Now, to prove the above universal statement, I would **start from all cases where the antecedent evaluates to true**. I will break down all of these cases (one of which has 3 subcases). The cases or subcases that have "contradictions" will be highlighted in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$.

---

**Case 1:** In English..."$a$ is in $X$, but $a$ is not in $Y \setminus X$"

$a \in X \text{ is True }, (a \notin Y \lor a \in X) \text{ is True}$

$\color{red}{\text{Subcase 1A}}$: $a \in X \text{ is True}, a \notin Y \text{ is True}, a \notin X \text { is True}$

$\text{Subcase 1B}$: $a \in X \text{ is True}, a \in Y \text{ is True}, a \in X \text{ is True}$

$\text {Subcase 1C}$: $a \in X \text{ is True},a \notin Y \text{ is True},a \in X \text{ is True}$

---

**Case 2:** In English... "$a$ is not in $X$, but $a$ is in $Y \setminus X$"

$a \notin X \text{ is True }, (a \in Y \land a \notin X) \text{ is True}$

$\text{Subcase 2A}$: $a \notin X \text{ is True }, a \in Y \text{ is True}, a \notin X \text{ is True}$.

---

$\color{red}{\text{Case 3}}$: In English... "$a$ is in $X$, and $a$ is in $Y \setminus X$"

$a \in X \text{ is True}, (a \in Y \land a \notin X) \text{ is True}$

$\color{red}{\text{Subcase 3A}}$: $a \in X \text{ is True}, a \in Y \text{ is True}, a \notin X \text{ is True}$

---

So my question basically breaks down to the following: **What do I do with these contradictions?** Do I simply "ignore" them and only work with the "non-contradictions"?

If I *am supposed to ignore them*, why exactly is that so? I don't really understand what a contradiction IS when it comes to how one makes logical arguments. What would happen if *all cases were purely contradictions*? Would the implication (from which these cases derive) simply be vacuously true? Cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: Nope, you don't have to worry about those contradictions.

---

> Converting this into a first order statement that I want to prove (if this is incorrect, please let me know and I will change it for clarity):
>
> $$\forall a,X,Y\big(a \in X \cup (Y\setminus X) \rightarrow a \in X \cup Y\big)$$

$X$ and $Y$ are free variables, so should not be quantified.   $X\cup(Y\smallsetminus X)\subseteq X\cup Y$ equates to the claim:

$$\forall a~\big(a\in X\cup(Y\smallsetminus X)\to a\in X\cup Y\big)$$

> Now, to prove the above universal statement, I would start from all cases where the antecedent evaluates to true.

Somewhat.   The antecedent is true when the arbitrary entity $a$ is in $X$ or it is in $Y\smallsetminus X$.   You only have to consider *these two cases*, which may or may not be disjoint.   If both cases each entails the conclusion, and those two cases **cover all possibilities**, then the conclusion is derivable.

$$\dfrac{P\vdash R\quad Q\vdash R\quad\vdash P\vee Q}{\vdash R}$$

**Note:** Indeed, when they are disjoint, their conjunction will be contradictory.   However, the Principle of Explosion applies: "from a contradiction, *anything* follows" (*ex falso quodlibet*).   So, you *do not have to worry* about the conjunction entailing a contradiction.

(Another way to view it: the *intersection* $X\cap(Y\smallsetminus X)$ is an empty set, which is a subset of any set.   That is $a\in X\cap(Y\smallsetminus X)\to a\in (X\cup Y)$ holds vacuously.)

So...

---

Taking an arbitrary element $a$, and assuming that $a\in X\cup(Y\smallsetminus X)$ we have two *exhaustive* cases:

Case 1: $a\in X$

- $a\in X$ entails $a\in X\vee a\in Y$ by rule of addition (disjunction introduction), which equates to $a\in X\cup Y$ by definition of set union.

Case 2: $a\in Y\smallsetminus X$

- $a\in Y\smallsetminus X$ equates to $a\in Y\wedge a\notin X$ by definition of set minus, which entails $a\in Y$ by rule of simplification (conjunction elimination), which again entails $a\in X\vee a\in Y$ by rule of addition (disjunction elimination), and so entails $a\in X\cup Y$ by definition of set union.

So $a\in X\cup (Y\smallsetminus X)$ does entail $a\in X\cup Y$.   Since that $a$ was arbitrary, we conclude $\forall a~(a\in X\cup(Y\smallsetminus X)\to a\in X\cup Y)$, which proves that which was to be proven by definition of subset$_{eq}$ .

$$\therefore~ ~X\cup(Y\smallsetminus X)\subseteq X\cup Y$$

Comment: Very helpful! Quick question, though. When you state that $X$ and $Y$ are free variables, does that mean that one has to "reprove" the proposition every time a new $X$ set and $Y$ set are used? (Say, for example, an $X' \neq X$ and a $Y' \neq Y$). Obviously, the proof would be identical except for switching the symbol $X'$ for $X$ and the symbol $Y'$ for $Y$...so I guess this "reproof" is carried out implicitly. Is that the gist?

Comment: (That's why I wanted to use the universal quantifier...to suggest that it doesn't matter what  sets $X$ and $Y$ are)

Comment: Because $A$ and $B$ are free in $A\subseteq A\cup B$ they must be free in any equivalent statement; as they are in $\forall x~(x\in A\to x\in A\cup B)$ . However, as these statements are provable tautologies (ie. theorems) they are provable for any interpretation of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly understand, so I will write a follow up question. Thanks for all of the information.